# Vary the size of an excel table based of the size of another table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a Macro that will take in data on one sheet of my workbook, and create a set of output data on another sheet. I have two tables, Input_Data (on the Data sheet) and Output_Data (on the DI) sheet.

```
Public Sub resize()
Dim inputTable As ListObject
Dim outputTable As ListObject
Dim sizeInput As Long
Dim sizeOutput As Long
Set inputTable = Sheets("Data").ListObjects("Input_Data")
Set ouputTable = Sheets("DI").ListObjects("Output_Data")
sizeInput = inputTable.Range.Rows.Count
sizeOutput = outputTable.Range.Rows.Count


Do While sizeInput > sizeOutput
    ouputTable.ListRows.Add
Loop

End Sub
```

Above is what I have so far from looking at other posts. When I try to run it I get a runtime error '91': "Object variable or With block variable not set. I'm guessing I'm referencing things wrong somewhere, but I'm not sure where. I would also like this to run continuously, or at least run when data is added to the Input_Data column, or trigger when people switch from the Data sheet to another. Not really sure what would cause the least amount of lag. I currently have this code in the "ThisWorkbook" object, not sure if that's the right place.

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ListObject.Resize Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobject-resize-method-excel)

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ResizeList()

    Dim table1 As ListObject
    Dim table2 As ListObject

    Set table1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    Set table2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2")

    Dim rows_count As Long
    Dim columns_count As Long

    Dim x As String
    Dim y As String

    With table2
    rows_count = .Range.Rows.Count
    columns_count = .Range.Columns.Count
    End With

    With table1
    x = .Range.Cells(1, 1).Address
    y = .Range.Cells(rows_count, columns_count).Address
    .Resize Range(x & ":" & y)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified it slightly as my second table has a different number of columns from my input table. Do you know if there is a way to make this run whenever an update is made or someone switches tabs? I'd like it so the resizing occurs automatically so people can't forget.

Comment: When update is made: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel

Comment: When the worksheet is activated: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-activate-event-excel

Comment: If you found my answer usefull i'll appreciate if you could mark it as an acceptable answer :)